# WPF how to use DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool to solve a design time error "cannot create an instance"?

Tags: wpf, design-time

I have the following class that I use in order to populate a combo box:

```
public class DamageTypeList
{
    static Begbil2Entities _DB = new Begbil2Entities();
    public static List<HUB_DamageTypes> _list = (from d in _DB.HUB_DamageTypes orderby d.DamageOrder select d).ToList(); 

    public static List<HUB_DamageTypes> TList
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
    }
 }
```

In the xaml file I add it like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <me:DamageTypeList  x:Key="DamageTypeList"/>
```

The xaml line creates an error (ONLY in design time, it runs pefectly at runtime):

Cannot create an instance of "DamageTypeList".  C:\HUB\HUB\HubbCostOfferPage.xaml

I have found some suggestions to solve it by using:

```
if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
```

But how do I use it to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the flag DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool to prevent the DB creation and to use hardcoded entities in your list.

```
public class DamageTypeList
{
    static Begbil2Entities _DB;
    public static List<HUB_DamageTypes> _list;

    public static Begbil2Entities DB
    {
        get
        {
            if(_DB == null && !DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
                _DB = new Begbil2Entities();
            return _DB;
        }
    }

    public static List<HUB_DamageTypes> TList
    {
        get
        {
            if(_list == null)
            {
                if(!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
                    _list = (from d in DB.HUB_DamageTypes orderby d.DamageOrder select d).ToList(); 
                else
                    _list = new List<HUB_DamageTypes>(){
                        // Initialize it with hardcoded values
                    };
            }
            return _list;
        }
    }
 }
```

Before doing that, tough, I would investigate a little further what is the cause of the design-time exception, as @fhlamarche suggested. You can try to debug the design time execution, is not that hard. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2008/06/19/debugging-design-time-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: WOW!!! I can't believe it, you actually solved my problem!!! :-)
You are really really clever. Thank you SOOO much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The designer attempts to call the default constructor but your class doesn't have one.
You just need to add a `private` or `internal` default constructor to your class.

Comment: I thought so too and tried it (one of the first things I tried). But that didn't help.